# ExtJs 4 + Zend (file structure) - Ext.Loader issue?

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework, extjs4

I am just writing my first app with Zend and ExtJs 4 and I neen urgent help please

The problem is :

I have Zend controller in wchich there are two actions : indexAction() and appAction()
I have also enabled layout for whole app. Each view is using this layout.

When I am hitting login button then I am redirecting to :

```
window.location = App.baseUrl + '/login/app';
```

where App.baseUrl - javascript object containing Zend base app path

It is redirecting me to the Zend View which looks like this :

```
<html lang="pl">
    <head>
        <!--extjs app-->
        <?php echo $this->headScript()->setFile($this->baseUrl().'/js/jsapp/app.js') ?>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

app.js file looks like this

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});
Ext.require('Ext.container.Container');

Ext.application({
    name: 'POB',
    appFolder: 'app',
    controllers: ['Orders'], <<---------
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
            layout: 'fit',
            height: '100%',
            renderTo: 'content',
            items: [
                  {
                    xtype: 'tabpanel',
                    title: 'Panel klienta',
                    items: [
                        {
                            //xtype: 'panel',
                            title: 'Zamówienia',
                            html: 'zamówienia bla bla bla',
                            items: [
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            //xtype: 'tabpanel',
                            title: 'Towar',
                            html: 'moja oferta bla bla'
                        },
                        {
                            //xtype: 'tabpanel',
                            title: 'Dane teleadresowe',
                            html: 'dane teleadresowe bla bla'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Please take a look in above script at line which is marked by arrow (<<-------)

when the line is commented everything is ok and application is launching correctly in the div="content" (renderTo: 'content')

When I unncoment this line then I got this error in chrome console

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html.
Orders.js:1Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I think there is no error in Orders.js file - it looks like this :

```
Ext.define('POB.controller.Orders', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
        console.log('Initialized Users! This happens before the Application launch function is called');
    }
});
```

Any ideas guys ? I'll be grateful for help

Comment: What is the use of the property 'controllers' in application method?

Comment: to include controller class which is in controller direcotry, in this case it should refear to Orders.js where controller is defined
And I thinks it's working correctly in this case. I think that error apears later when parsing Order.js file (or while including this file to zend view? ) , but not sure

Answer (score 0):

You should check your Orders.js file, there is something wrong there hence the error message:

```
Orders.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Uncommenting that line triggers the loading and interpreting of that file.